# Find a formula for a degree four polynomial function f that might have this graph.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have a graph image that the line touches on the x-axis the values $-4, -2, 0$, and $1$.

I believe that part of the answer is $f(x) = (x+4)(x+2)(x-1)$, but what is the forth zero?

Edit: On the graph image, the line doesn't actually go through the point -4, but hovers directly above it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Touching the $x$-axis" occurs when $f(x) = 0$.

How can you modify your function so that $f(0) = 0$?

Comment: @B I tried adding a (x+0), am I getting closer?

Comment: What do you mean by "adding"? What's your new $f(x)$? And what happens when you try $f(x)$ for $x = -4, -2, 0$ and $1$? Do you get $0$?

Comment: @B The new function is f(x)=(x+4)(x+2)(x-1)(x-0). That doesn't work though, but I am hoping I'm going in the right direction..

Comment: That new function will certainly give you all the $0$'s you described. Though more often one would use the notation $x$ instead of $(x-0)$, so that it would be: $f(x) = (x+4)(x+2)(x-1)x$. Can you check the value of your graph at any point besides $x = -4, -2, 0$ or $1$? If so, what is the point, what *should* the output be, and what output are you getting with your current $f(x)$?

Comment: @B Just realized something, on the graph, the line doesn't actually go through the point -4 on the x-axis, it almost hovers right over it. The line does go through 1, 0, and 2. Would that effect my answer?

Comment: It certainly would! The important thing to understand is what your graph is: for each value of $x$, you draw a dot at $f(x)$. When you see the function touching the $x$-axis at the point $a$, it means that $f(a) = 0$. In particular, it means your function looks like $f(x) = (x-a)*something$. If it touches down at $-4$ but doesn't actually go through the $x$-axis, try replacing $(x+4)$ in your proposed function with $(x+4)^2$. Does this give you the right graph?

Comment: @B Yes it does, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest you do some deep thinking about why changing your function as above gave the desired graph; I won't say anything more about it here, but be sure to ask your teacher/instructor if you are still unclear on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

Answer would be $f(x) = x(x-1)(x+2)(x+4) $. This will give you all the zeros you are looking for. Trick is to make sure your function is zero at each of the values 0,1,-2, and -4.

Comment: this probably would be the right answer if that was the question that my homework was telling me :)